# SQL - Case In Where Clause to reduce IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Getting errors when I try to execute. I'm not a DBA but I need this to filter in the where clause based on my variable being passed in. I had it working using a massive statement with IF statements but that looked really bad so I came up with this idea but getting errors.

Query:

```
    DECLARE
    @VariableName AS NVARCHAR(100),
    @VariableValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @PileFrom AS INT,
    @PileTo AS INT,
    @BeginDate AS DATETIME,
    @EndDate AS DATETIME,
    @Truck AS BIT,
    @Train AS BIT
--AS
BEGIN
    IF @BeginDate = '' BEGIN
        SET @Begindate = '1/1/1900'
    END

    IF @EndDate = '' BEGIN
        SET @EndDate = '1/1/9999'
    END 

    IF @Truck = 1 BEGIN
        SELECT 
            Car_ID,
            PO_Number,
            Vendor,
            Shipper,
            Commodity,
            Date_Weighed_In,
            Date_Weighed_Out,
            Pile_No AS 'PILe From',
            Pile_No1 AS 'Pile To',
            Operator_In,
            Operator_Out,
            Comments_In,
            Comments_Out,
            Weight_In,
            Weight_Out,
            Transaction_Num,
            Record_time_Stamp
        FROM
            dbo.Transactions_Truck
        WHERE
            (Date_Weighed_IN BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) AND
            CASE 
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbCardID'         THEN Car_ID = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbPONumber'       THEN PO_Number = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbVendor'         THEN Vendor = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbCommodity'      THEN Commodity = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbPileNumber'     THEN Pile_No = @PileFrom AND Pile_No1 = @PileTo
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbTransactionNum' THEN Transaction_Num = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbOperator'       THEN Operator_In = @VariableValue
                WHEN @VariableName = 'rbComments'       THEN Comments_In = @VariableValue           
        END ELSE IF @Train = 1 BEGIN
            SELECT 
                Car_ID,
                PO_Number,
                Vendor,
                Shipper,
                Commodity,
                Date_Weighed_In,
                Date_Weighed_Out,
                Pile_No AS 'PILe From',
                Pile_No1 AS 'Pile To',
                Operator_In,
                Operator_Out,
                Comments_In,
                Comments_Out,
                Weight_In,
                Weight_Out,
                Transaction_Num,
                Record_time_Stamp
            FROM
                dbo.Transactions_train
            WHERE
                (Date_Weighed_IN BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) AND
                CASE 
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbCardID'         THEN Car_Id = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbPONumber'       THEN PO_Number = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbVendor'         THEN Vendor = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbCommodity'      THEN Commodity = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbPileNumber'     THEN Pile_No = @PileFrom AND Pile_No1 = @PileTo
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbTransactionNum' THEN Transaction_Num = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbOperator'       THEN Operator_In = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbComments'       THEN Comments_In = @VariableValue
                    WHEN @VariableName = 'rbRailRoad'       THEN Rail_Road = @VariableValue
        END
END
```

Comment: Any hints on what those errors were? I hate guessing games.

Comment: Do you have `END` for your case?

Comment: Your `@BeginDate` and `@EndDate` variables are datetimes, so you should probably compare them to NULL instead of '', since dates can't be an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do your where statement like that.. you should just use AND and OR

```
WHERE   (Date_Weighed_IN BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate)
        AND (
                (@VariableName = 'rbCardID'         AND Car_Id          = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbPONumber'       AND PO_Number       = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbVendor'         AND Vendor          = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbCommodity'      AND Commodity       = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbPileNumber'     AND Pile_No         = @PileFrom         
                                                    AND Pile_No1        = @PileTo       )
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbTransactionNum' AND Transaction_Num = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbOperator'       AND Operator_In     = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbComments'       AND Comments_In     = @VariableValue)
            OR  (@VariableName = 'rbRailRoad'       AND Rail_Road       = @VariableValue)
        )
```

Comment: that looks great ill test in a few

Answer (score 1):

`JamieD77`'s answer should do the work, but many ORs might get you into performance trouble, so I would also consider using a `dynamic SQL` to try to obtain a much more smaller SQL statement to be executed (this is not tested and I have reformatted to make it more readable):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = '
   SELECT Car_ID, PO_Number, Vendor, Shipper, Commodity, Date_Weighed_In, Date_Weighed_Out, Pile_No AS [PILe From],
            Pile_No1 AS [Pile To], Operator_In, Operator_Out, Comments_In, Comments_Out, Weight_In, Weight_Out,
            Transaction_Num, Record_time_Stamp
        FROM dbo.Transactions_Truck
        WHERE (Date_Weighed_IN BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate)'

-- merge conditions that are common to @Train = 0 and @Train = 1
IF (@VariableName = 'rbCardID') @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N' AND Car_ID = @VariableValue'
IF (@VariableName = 'rbPONumber') @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N' AND PO_Number = @VariableValue'
-- other conditions come here
IF (@VariableName = 'rbComments') @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N' AND Comments_In = @VariableValue'

IF (@Train = 1 AND @VariableName = 'rbRailRoad') @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N' AND Rail_Road = @VariableValue'

-- for debugging purposes
PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@BeginDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @VariableValue NVARCHAR(MAX)', 
   @BeginDate = @BeginDate, @EndDate = @EndDate, @VariableValue = @VariableValue
```

This way your code is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and I think you should be faster (I do not know if the engine knows to optimize all those ORs and that might be even worse than the performance that might be lost using dynamic queries).

An even better approach is to make comparisons in a typed manner. I cannot see your data types for all the columns compared to `@VariableValue`, but I assume that Ids and dates are not strings. If the types are different from `NVARCHAR`, an implicit cast will be generated for each type non-match and performance will degrade.

However, this would require a complete rewrite of your logic using Entity Framework (it should not be hard, if this is all what your procedure is doing and it is good exercise) or something similar.

Comment: I really like Dynamic SQL don't get me wrong but it really is not best practices so  I hear. An I try to make things as simple as I can for the guy coming in behind me. So if this was a personal project I would totally use the Dynamic SQL but its a Corp project. Thank you though for the Dynamic sample, its very helpful and thank you for the other solution.

Comment: Things that do not repeat are easier to understand and maintain. Whoever sees the code asks (at least I did) what is the difference between @Train = 0 or 1, as the code is almost identical. Dynamic SQL is not recommended because it [has some tricks](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22932/why-you-want-to-avoid-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure), but in some cases it can be good. Large queries containg many OR conditions are harder to optimize by the engine (and harder to understand by human beings).